# How to Reset Credit Card Form after Submit the Form in Square Connect

Tags: angular, angular7, square-connect

In Square Connect, I am creating Credit Card Nonce using sqPaymentForm. Once I submit the form and create the Nonce, I would like to reset form/clear all 
 textboxes. I am using Angular 7 and FormGroup doesn't work with the sqPaymentForm. so how can I reset my form on form Submit?

```
this.paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

        // Initialize the payment form elements
        applicationId: this.applicationId,
        locationId: this.locationId,
        autoBuild: false,
        inputClass: 'sq-input',
        // Initialize the credit card placeholders
        cardNumber: {
          elementId: 'sq-card-number',
          placeholder: 'Valid Card Number'
        },
        cvv: {
          elementId: 'sq-cvv',
          placeholder: 'CVV'
        },
        expirationDate: {
          elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
          placeholder: 'Expiration'
        },
        postalCode: {
          elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
          placeholder: 'Zip Code'
        },
        // SqPaymentForm callback functions
        callbacks: {
          /*
           * callback function: methodsSupported
           * Triggered when: the page is loaded.
           */

          /*
           * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
           * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
           */
          cardNonceResponseReceived: (errors, nonce, cardData) => {
            if (errors) {
              // Log errors from nonce generation to the Javascript console
              console.log("Encountered errors:");
              errors.forEach(function (error) {
                console.log('  ' + error.message);
              });
              return;
            }

            this.updateCustomerCard(nonce, cardData.billing_postal_code);
          },

          /*
           * callback function: paymentFormLoaded
           * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm is fully loaded
           */
          paymentFormLoaded: function () {
            /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          }
        }
      });

      this.paymentForm.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to directly edit any of the fields, so you won't be able to reset the fields one-by-one. However, you do have the ability to call [destroy()](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/paymentform#destroy) on the payment form, and then call [build()](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/paymentform#build) to rebuild the form (which would essentially reset all of the fields).

Comment: Is possible with real-time inventory sync with square and Magento 1.x? @sjosey

Comment: @sjosey is there any option in square payment sdk to payment with saved card data ? don't want to enter card data every time.

Comment: Yes, you can save cards on file after receiving a nonce: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/transactions-api/cookbook/save-cards-on-file and charge it just by passing the `card_id` into the `source_id` of the Payments API.